# Too many redirects error while trying to configure rails application as SSL using nginx and unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, unicorn

I am trying to configure a Rails application with SSL, using Nginx and Unicorn. 
I am trying to set it up locally. For that I first created a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL for Nginx. I followed the [document](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04) for creating self-signed certificates. After that I configured my `nginx.conf` as below, inside the `http` block:

```
upstream unicorn_myapp {
    # This is the socket we configured in unicorn.rb
    server unix:root_path/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.myapp.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://dev.myapp.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen                80;
    listen                443 ssl;
    server_name           dev.myapp.com;
    ssl                   on;
    ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/server.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_protocols         SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers           ALL:-ADH:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP;
    ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:10m;

    root root_path/public;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://unicorn_myapp;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set it up locally, and started Unicorn locally. I mapped `127.0.0.1` to `dev.myapp.com` in `/etc/hosts`. But after starting the server, when I tried to ping the app, it gave the below error in Chrome:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

and the following error in Firefox:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

The `nginix.access.log` shows the following result:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:16 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;        Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:16 +0530] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:16 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:16 +0530] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:16 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:12:56:43 +0530] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

Can any one please help me out to find the solution?

Comment: It looks like your 80 rewrite goes to http (80 again), should be https ?

Comment: How can we change that in above configuration?

Comment: Try changing 'rewrite ^/(.*) http://...' to 'rewrite ^/(.*) https://...' and remove listen 80 from the 2nd server block

Comment: @house9 - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn no worries I'll plus one your answer

Answer (score 78):

You are missing a header:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

Let me cite a comprehensive [post](http://seaneshbaugh.com/posts/configuring-nginx-and-unicorn-for-force_ssl) that explains nicely how Rails deals with HTTPS on Nginx:

> `force_ssl` relies on the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` HTTP header to determine whether or not the request was an HTTPS request. If this setting isn't set to `https` then you will end up with an infinite redirect loop as `force_ssl` will always think the forwarded request isn't HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> Try changing 'rewrite ^/(.*) http://...' to 'rewrite ^/(.*) https://...' and remove listen 80 from the 2nd server block

~ answer per [house9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317989/house9)