# HTTPS for Rails Application - InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to get `https` to work for my rails application. When i try to do any post related activity on the application i am getting the following error.

```
Exception `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken' at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:195 - ActionCon
troller::InvalidAuthenticityToken
Exception `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken' at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:23 - ActionController::InvalidAuthe
nticityToken
Exception `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken' at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:25 - ActionController
::InvalidAuthenticityToken
Exception `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken' at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:42 - ActionController::Invali
dAuthenticityToken
Exception `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken' at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:77 - ActionController:
:InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

Comment: Can you post a copy of your controller code?  Are you using any authentication gems such as Devise?  If so, which version?  Also, does this work without SSL?

Comment: @TomAranda it works perfect with http. when i post its getting posted to http on form submission from https

Comment: Is your entire session on https?  In other words, are all of your requests to load the form GET and to post the form over https?  If not, perhaps rails is using different sessions that that is causing the authenticity token to fail.

Comment: @TomAranda yes looks like it. Any idea how to make sure all of it is on https?

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding this to your `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.force_ssl = true
end
```

If you want this to take effect in the other environments, add it to
the appropriate environment file as well.

Comment: Let me test this out :)

Comment: Awesome this works. Had to add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` in nginx config as well :)

Comment: Note to these using **nginx** as a reverse proxy: you'll need to add the line `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` to your `/sites-available/*` file. See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21793954/4714567)

Comment: For apache, had to add ```RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}``` and also enable the headers module: ```sudo a2enmod headers```